# How to display in the Next Page of JQuery DataTables from the Previous Datatables page. I'm using ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, asp.net-routing

I have `page-1.cshtml` that displays employee information using jQuery data tables. Then the last column of the table, I added `href link` so the user can click the link and navigate to the `page-2.cshtml` that displays a specific record of the employee. The problem is, when I Click and navigate to the next page which has another jQuery Datables to display the record of an employee, it displays `Datatables Warning: table id = mydatatableservice - ajax error. 
For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`.

But if I change my route like this:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ServiceRecord", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

`page-2.cshtml`, it displays good.

Any idea?